# Creating a boolean method to check for consecutive numbers

Tags: java, methods, boolean

I need help writing a method that checks if numbers and text are consecutive. It needs to return a boolean value of true if an input like inputted deFgh or 456789 and false for anything else not consecutive. I don't understand how to make the loop be true for cases like xyZaBcD and 890123 or cbazyx

Comment: What are you tried? Do you have some code?

Comment: You can scan the text and maintain flags meaning "all characters are digits so far" and "all characters are letters so far". Hope that helps.

Comment: Try to do your homework yourself. This is the reason it is called homework. do not worry, it is fun. If you fail try to find solution in internet. There are a lot, believe me. if you have specific problems with your implentation come back here.

Comment: The beautiful thing about programming is that it's raw logic. It's you vs. fundamental thinking. You have full control over what the computer does. Start writing test cases on paper and think about how you would do those specific cases. Then start making your algorithm more and more general until it covers all cases. Start with something simple like numbers, then expand it to letters.

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

```
public static boolean isConsecutive(final String s) throws IllegalArgumentException
{
    if (null == s) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    if (s.length() <= 1) return true;

    final String lc = s.toLowerCase();
    char c = lc.charAt(0);
    for (int cc=1; cc<lc.length(); cc++)
        if ( (c+1) != lc.charAt(cc) )
            return false;
        else
            c++;

    return true;
} 

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try
    {
        System.out.println(isConsecutive("456789"));
        System.out.println(isConsecutive("deFgh"));
        System.out.println(isConsecutive("xyZaBcD"));
        System.out.println(isConsecutive("890123"));
    }
    catch(final Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

but I really suggest you do not show it to teacher, as it will have more questions, use it only as direction to your own code

Answer (score 1):

This can be implemented at easiest way:

```
public class Check {
    private static boolean checkConsecutive(String str) {
            str = str.toLowerCase();
            if (str.length() == 1) return true;

        for (int i = 1; i < str.length(); i++) {
            String first = str.substring(i, i+1);
            String beforeFirst = str.substring(i-1, i);

            if (beforeFirst.compareTo(first) > 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Check obj = new Check();

        System.out.printf("abcdef is: %s%n", obj.checkConsecutive("abcdef"));
        System.out.printf("12345 is: %s%n", obj.checkConsecutive("12345"));
        System.out.printf("54321 is: %s%n", obj.checkConsecutive("54321"));
        System.out.printf("fedcba is: %s%n", obj.checkConsecutive("fedcba"));
    }
}
```

Output will be next:

```
abcdef is: true
12345 is: true
54321 is: false
fedcba is: false
```

This line `str.substring(i, i+1)` return exactly one letter, and we can use `compareTo()` from String class it compares consecutive by itself.

Comment: @user2896303 Why you didn't accept this answer at this case?

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate over string and check sequence of char codes. If needed, use toLowerCase() method.

Comment: You need to know where to loop back at, and loop back to. This will be different for letters and numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast (int) to the characters in the loop. If the integer is between 48 and 57 inclusive, that means that the character is a digit.

See ASCII Table for the integers given by casting from char.

Comment: you could improve this by adding example code, and by making sure your terminology is precise ("you can cast chars to int" would be clearer).